# Optimize PNG format for iPhone using Java on Windows instead of pngcrush

Tags: java, iphone, windows, png

I'm creating PNG images using a Java application on Windows. Those images will be transferred to a my iPhone App later on.

At the moment the App is spending a lot of time decompressing the PNG images according to instruments.

When manually using the pngcrush tool on Mac to optimize the PNGs the decompression on the iPhone is much faster. But normally the images should be transferred directly without needing a Mac.

How can you to create optimized PNGs for the iPhone on a Windows computer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's wrong with using the Win32/EXE version of pngcrush?

The precompiled Win32 executables seem to be available from sourceforge.net: [pngcrush Win32 executables](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pmt/files/pngcrush-executables/)

[EDIT]
Brad was nice enough to inform me that the open-source pngcrush is not the same as Apple's pngcrush (the open-source pngcrush has been around longer AFAIK).

You want the Win32 version of pincrush: [pincrush website](http://howett.net/pincrush/) which supposedly mimics the changes that Apple's pngcrush app performs.

Comment: This application entitled pngcrush is not the same as Apple's pngcrush tool.  As I explain in my answer, Apple's pngcrush does some byte reordering rather than any image compression.

Comment: edited answer to refer to a suitable Win32 app which functions like  Apple's pngcrush app

Comment: Good find.  That should do what they want.

Answer (score 2):

Jeff LaMarche documents what pngcrush actually does to the images in his article [here](http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2008/10/iphone-optimized-pngs.html), and Andrew Grant shows some sample code for doing this onboard the iPhone in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/640909/performing-iphone-optimization-on-externally-downloaded-pngs/644021#644021) to [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/640909/performing-iphone-optimization-on-externally-downloaded-pngs).

Basically, pngcrush appears to change the byte order of the image to be BGR and premultiplies the alpha channel.

Perhaps you could modify your Java application to output PNG files in this format, which wouldn't be that hard to generate.

Answer (score 0):

Try this : http://psydk.org/PngOptimizer.php

I've used it before and it's pretty good.

Comment: Does that produce PNG files in the specific compressed format expected  by the iPhone?  I thought the iPhone crushed format was something nonstandard.

Comment: It turns out that all pngcrush does is invert the color component byte order and premultiplies the alpha, according to Jeff LaMarche: http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2008/10/iphone-optimized-pngs.html , so this optimizer wouldn't do what you want.